# How can I perform node fields updates without processing all the node_save() stuff?

Tags: nodes, entities, updating

I am trying to update node fields directly with [db_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7.x):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $_POST_value) {

  $num_updated = db_update('field_data_krown_weight')
  ->fields(array(
    'krown_weight_value' => $_POST_value['weight'],
  ))
  ->condition('entity_id', $_POST_value['nid1'], '=')
  ->execute();

}
```

It works pretty well, the data is well updated into database, and very fast. The problem is that when I go to the node form edit, the value in my field hasn't been updated.

I read that we must use [field_attach_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7.x) instead, something like:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $_POST_value) {

  $node1 = node_load($_POST_value['nid1']);
  $node1->krown_weight['und'][0]['value'] = $_POST_value['weight'];
  field_attach_update('node', $node1);

}
```

The problem is that with [field_attach_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7.x), the query takes much more time to be executed! I need to update several nodes at the same time, so I would like to avoid [field_attach_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7.x)..

How can I perform node fields updates without processing all the [node_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7.x) stuff?

I also tried to reset the cache after [db_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7.x), but this doesn't seems to work:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $_POST_value) {

  $num_updated = db_update('field_data_krown_weight')
  ->fields(array(
    'krown_weight_value' => $_POST_value['weight'],
  ))
  ->condition('entity_id', $_POST_value['nid1'], '=')
  ->execute();

  entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($_POST_value['nid1']));

}
```